# Read Scores from text file and sort into array

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

Im trying to get my test score program to work. Whenever I type in the pathfile to read from the text file the program would read 4 out of the 5 numbers that are there.Also, no matter what number there are it is always going to display my minimum as 0 when it is not true. Any help is truly appreciated!

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exam{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Welcome!" + "\n");

 //File location
    System.out.println("Where is the data file:");
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userFile = userInput.nextLine();

    int i = 0;
    int scores[] = readScores(userFile);

    System.out.println("Minimum score: " + scores[0]);
    System.out.println("Maximum score: " + scores[(scores.length - 1)]);

 //Average Calculation
    double gradesTotal = 0;
    for (i=0; i<scores.length; ++i){
        gradesTotal = gradesTotal + scores[i];
    }
    double mean = gradesTotal/scores.length;
    System.out.println("Average score: " + mean);

 //Mean Calculation
    double median;
    if (scores.length % 2 == 0)
        median = ((scores[(scores.length/2) - 1]) + scores[(scores.length/2)]) / 2;
    else
        median = scores[(scores.length/2)];
    System.out.println("Median score: " + median + "\n");

    //Number of Grades
    int gradeA = 0;
    int gradeB = 0;
    int gradeC = 0;
    int gradeD = 0;
    int gradeF = 0;


    for (i=0; i<scores.length; i++)
    {
        if (scores[i] >= 90 && scores[i] <=100){
            gradeA++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] <= 89 && scores[i] >=80){
            gradeB++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] <= 79 && scores[i] >=70){
            gradeC++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] <= 69 && scores[i] >=60){
            gradeD++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] <= 59 && scores[i] >=1){

            gradeF++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Scores by letter grade: ");
    System.out.println("A: " + gradeA);
    System.out.println("B: " + gradeB);
    System.out.println("C: " + gradeC);
    System.out.println("D: " + gradeD);
    System.out.println("F: " + gradeF);
}

//Reads the data from the submitted file
private static int[] readScores(String userFile) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File inputFile = new File(userFile);
    Scanner stats = new Scanner(inputFile);

    try {
        int scores[] = new int[stats.nextInt()];
        int i = 0;
        while (stats.hasNext()){
            scores[i] = stats.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "There are " + (i) + " scores" + "\n");
        Arrays.sort(scores);
        return scores;
    }
    finally {
        stats.close();
    }
 }
}
```

Text file:

```
72
31
13 
39
74
```

Program output:

```
There are 4 scores

Minimum score: 0
Maximum score: 74
Average score: 2.1805555555555554
Median score: 0.0

Number of scores by letter grade: 
A: 0
B: 0
C: 1
D: 0
F: 3
```

Comment: Look carefully at what you are doing with the first line of the scores file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int scores[] = new int[stats.nextInt()];
```

here you take the first of your values and then you dont have it where you need it.

That is probably also the reason why your calculations are so messed up. you create an array of lenght 72 and use that lenght for the number of values.

Maybe you want to use a list instead. It allows you to add as many values as you want without specifying a number like you have to do when you use an array.

Comment: how could i change it to a list?

Comment: Easy,  `List list = new LinkedList();` to create one (linked list is not the only type of list, there are quite many)
        `list.add(stats.nextInt());` to add the next int to the list
        `list.size();` to get the size of the list
        `list.toArray();` gives you an array of the list. you could do that after reading all the marks, so you don't have to change the other code.

Oh, and you will have to `import java.util.LinkedList;`
For more Information abouts lists see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html